# .htaccess issue with image handling

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect:

1. All pages to `index.php` (this is working).
2. `/products/large/12345.jpg` to `/classes/watermark/handler.php?size=large&photo=12345.jpg` (this is not).

---

```
### OPTIONS ###
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

### REWRITE ###
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

### CONDITIONS ###
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

### RULES ###
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/products/(.*)/(.*)$ /classes/watermark/handler.php?size=$1&photo=$2
```

---

The issue is that apache returns internal redirect error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the directives in the wrong order. You need to have the more specific rule first. Like you say, you are *rewriting* "all pages to `index.php`". If you have already written to `index.php`, how are you expected to rewrite `/products/....`?

However, you also have an error in your `RewriteRule` *pattern*. In `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched does not start with a slash. So, this will never match anyway.

Note also that `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the first `RewriteRule` that follows. `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives together form a single "rule". You shouldn't necessarily separate *conditions* and `RewriteRule` directives, they work together (and can "talk" to each other).

Try something like this instead:

```
# Rewrite images
RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)$ /classes/watermark/handler.php?size=$1&photo=$2 [L]

# Rewrite all other pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note I've also added the `L` (`last`) flag to prevent the following directive being processed.

Not sure why you had `[^?]*` as your pattern? The query string is not matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. So, this can probably be simplified to `.*` (as above).

Depending on your URL structure, you might also want to confirm that an image is being requested? ie. a request for a URL ending `.jpg`? Rather than something like `/products/large/<something>`. You could also validate the "size" ie. `(small|medium|large)`.

> The issue is that apache returns internal redirect error.

Well, I can't see where that would be happening in the code you posted? (As mentioned, in the code you posted, that additional directive wouldn't have done anything.)